# Processing registration errors in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM and I want to catch errors when registration and schedule retry.
This situation is [described](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html#retry) in documentation, but it seems that it is outdated.

At first, there is no `handleRegistration` method in `GCMBaseIntentService`. It is not a problem because we have `onError` method. The bigger problem is that it is impossible to override `onHandleIntent` because it is declared as final. So, I can send retry intent but I don't know how to correctly catch it. How can I do this?

And the second question. In the documentation it is adviced to pass some kind of verification token, which is actually a random long number. But can't we receive retry intent after service restart and have another value of this constant? How we can deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I found solution myself. If anyone is interested, see https://github.com/darja/gcmdemo.

Russian-speakers can also read http://megadarja.blogspot.ru/2012/12/google-cloud-messaging.html